# Bad SSL link on Stack Overflow blog pointing to Stack Overflow Enterprise site

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl, stack-overflow-enterprise

Looks like someone needs a new SSL Cert! Repro is:

1. Go to [Stack Overflow Blog](http://stackoverflow.blog/engineering/).
2. Click on this link in the page footer: [Get Stack Overflow Enterprise](https://stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise)

Expected: fascinating marketing content about this product.

Actual: 
[image: screen shot of insecure connection URL]

Comment: Able to duplicate. Getting SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN in Firefox.

Comment: + IE11 - Modifying https to http, I am redirected to https without error

Comment: @Carrosive Goes via a couple of redirects, which ends up inserting `www.`, which has a valid cert.

Comment: Get error `Your connection is not private` on Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 m details: Certificate Error
There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).

Answer (score 9):

This was an improper link created that should have pointed to the www. website. I pushed an update to fix them, it'll be live in 1 minute and 24 seconds. Now 22. Now 21. Okay hitting submit.